# EF Core 2.1 - Unable to create an object of type 'MyAppContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppContext>' to the project,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am using `ASP.Net Core 2.1` with `EF 2.1` This is how my Context class looks like

```
 public class MyAppContext
    : DbContext
{
    private string _dbConnection = @"Data Source=myServer;Database=SampleApp;uid=sa;password=******";
    public MyAppContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("app");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dbConnection);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my StartUp.cs & Program.cs looks like

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

}}
```

I checked below links:-

- [EF Core Migration error: "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343295/ef-core-migration-error-unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-applicationcontext)
- [EF Core 2.1 project Add-Migration NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961727/ef-core-2-1-project-add-migration-nullreferenceexception)

& few others.

But most of them were around when Migrating 1.x to 2.x but this is my fresh application. No migrations

How do I fix this error??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't a public constructor without parameters in your database class, so you need to tell a compiler how to create an instance of your database.

Just add a new class:

```
    internal class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppContext>
    {
        public MyAppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(_dbConnection);
            var context = new MyAppContext(builder.Options);
            return context;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Here's example how to obtain a `_dbConnection` for the desktop application.

```
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configBuilder.SetBasePath(currentDir);
configBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var config = configBuilder.Build();
_dbConnection = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried the same but could you please tell how _dbConnection will get value which is present in UI layer project's appsettings.json

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with web applications, so I just only include a code snippet I used in the desktop one.

Comment: Okay!! in that case how you're setting the value to _dbConnection??